# C++ Deleting a node from a tree when the node has two children

Tags: c++, tree

Suppose I had a tree as follows:

```
          8
     3         12
  4     5    6   15
1  2
```

If I wanted to delete 3, by replacing it with the lowest left node (in this case 1). 2 would then attach to 4, in that diagram.

How would I code this?

I know you have to keep traversing all the way left with some sort of loop, and then reset each of the pointers appropriately. Also, you have to account for the case where the last left node may have a right child.

Comment: What have you tried?  You should understand that we are not here to do your homework: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: You do *not* want to descend to the furthest-left node. You want either the furthest-right node of the left subtree, or the furthest-left node of the right subtree. Since `1` and `2` both descend to the *left* of `4`, you'd promote `4` to take the place of `3`, not `1` (if you move `1` up, then searching the tree would no longer work (its left descendant would be greater than it, violating the basic rules of the tree).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: The tree is already out of order. As I read it, the in order traversal is 1 2 4 3 5 8 6 12 15

Comment: @user315052: Yup -- I wasn't paying close enough attention.

Answer (score 0):

Before we tackle the "how", 2 things:

(1) - This is minor.  The question only makes sense in the context of a binary  *search*  tree (BST), not simply a binary tree.  And this tree is not a BST because the 3 and the 4 are swapped.

(2) - Any time you perform a deletion on a BST, and you want to "fix up" the tree such that the resulting tree is also a BST, you have two choices: (a) you can choose the largest value in the left subtree of the node to be deleted, or (b) you can choose the smallest value in the right subtree of the node to be deleted, and you swap it with the node to be deleted.  (You should convince yourself of why these options will both leave you with a BST).  In your example (with the 3 and the 4 correctly placed), this means swapping the 4 with either the 3 or the 5.

Now for the "how" to do it.  Let's say we chose option (a) from above.  What you'll need to do is write a function that, starting from the 4, will go one step left and then traverse right as long as it can (you should also convince yourself of why this is correct).  Once you can no longer traverse to the right, you know you've found the largest value in the left subtree.  Then, you swap this value in place of the node you want to delete, and then delete the node whose value you just took.

This is actually quite simple to code if you've figured out how to code the tree that you've presented here.  If you have code specific questions, please provide more detail